# Can KeyBy(key1 or key2) in FLINK?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a way in Flink to use keyby(key1 or key2) (ORing keys) I don't mean keyBy(0,1) I need to forward elements with key1 or elements with key2 to the same node.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward thing you can do is to write a KeySelector function that returns the same key for all events that you want to be treated together. Events that have the same key will be processed by the same node, and will share keyed state and timers, should that be relevant.

If you want the events to have different keys but still be processed by the same node (I confess I'm curious to know why this would be desirable), then you would need to arrange for them to be in the same key group. This becomes complex; see [this mailing list thread](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Use-keyBy-to-deterministically-hash-each-record-to-a-processor-task-slot-td16483.html&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1556548333682000&usg=AFQjCNFbd14LUiBrYj6WrYoHBVJ4ZBz6_Q) for some discussion of this.